# JQuery mobile bind event for single page model

Tags: jquery-mobile

Sorry to ask such a basic question on JQuery mobile, but I am not so clear.

With a single page model (split an app into multiple pages), all scripts are loaded at the landing page. However, UI elements (e.g. buttons) may not appear until several pages deep into the clicks. Where and how do I bind event that are not yet loaded? Or how do I bind event as the pages are loaded? `$(document).bind("pagecreate", function(){})` is just going to run on landing page, but I suppose I need to bind after the widgets have appeared.

I bind it like this:

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function(event, data) {
  $('#btn_newuser2').on('vclick', function(event) {
    // do something here.
  });
});
```

Comment: No, you are safe binding event handlers for all DOM elements in the `pagecreate` event.

Comment: Really? Let me check my code again as it wasn't firing.

Comment: That means all buttons in the app have to have unique IDs?

Comment: Different IDs, or you can use classes to group them

Comment: ...I bind events using [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), like this: `$(document).on("click", "#my_button", function(){});`

Comment: Hmm, the delegation works. But my original doesn't. Not familiar with delegation.

Comment: And apparently only works with click, not vclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are safe binding event handlers for all DOM elements in the `pagecreate` event, if you use [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_button", function()
{
    // handler
});
```

In this example the click event is binded to the whole document, but the second parameter is a selector for a child element. As stated in the docs:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future